# Access Query Match lowest unused number

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have got a query result in MSAccess.

```
QueryMatch :
InvoiceNumber   RegionNumber  Group
9448180         73657         A
9448180         74170         A
9448180         74171         A
9448180         78761         A
9448196         73657         A
9448196         74170         A
9448196         74171         A
9448196         78761         A
9448201         73657         A
9448201         74170         A
9448201         74171         A
9448201         78761         A

1234567         12345         B
so on..

Table 2:
RegionNumber  InvoiceNumber
73657
74170
74171
78761
```

The query has a long list , separated by groups.
There can be x + n  RegionNumber for x InvoiceNumbers.
n = 0 to 25.
**One RegionNumber must be matched with One InvoiceNumber only for each group.** 
How do we update Table2?

Let us do for smallest RegionNumber to match smallest InvoiceNumber within the Matchresult.

Leaving the last RegionNumber NULL.

Please provide a VBA or can this be done with queries alone ?
Selecting MIN (InvoiceNumber) for each RegionNumber will result in the same InvoiceNumber.

Thanks

Comment: Your question hints that you may have already tried something like `SELECT RegionNumber, MIN(InvoiceNumber) AS MinOfInvoiceNumber FROM QueryMatch GROUP BY RegionNumber`. If so, please edit your question to indicate more clearly why that approach was unsatisfactory. Do the `RegionNumber,InvoiceNumber` pairs in [Table2] need to be distinct?

Comment: yes, have tried that. Yes RegionNumber-InvoiceNumber pair must be distinct.

Comment: ...and those sample rows for [Table 2] are just the results for Group="A", correct? (If so, it might have been clearer if you had put `Group` as the first column.)

Comment: Have just mentioned samples from Group A in Table 2.
Table 2 will not have the groups mentioned , only RegionNumbers.
We got to do for all groups in the result. There will be many groups.

Comment: ...so if RegionNumber 73657 appears in Groups "A" and "B" should it appear in [Table2] only once? ...or should it appear twice (with a different InvoiceNumber, I assume)...?

Comment: that case is not possible , the RegionNumbers and InvoiceNumbers belonging to one group will not occur in the other group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the following [QueryMatch] sample data

```
InvoiceNumber   RegionNumber    Group
123             678             A
234             678             A
345             678             A
123             789             A
```

We *could* try to just iterate through the RegionNumber values (ascending) and pick the lowest InvoiceNumber, but that approach will ultimately fail. We would assign InvoiceNumber 123 to RegionNumber 678 and then when it comes time to process RegionNumber 789 the only possible choice would be InvoiceNumber 123 and it has already been taken.

So, we'd better start by getting a list of the RegionNumber values and the number of distinct InvoiceNumbers that each one has. That will let us process the most constrained RegionNumber values first.

```
SELECT qm.RegionNumber, Count(qm.InvoiceNumber) AS NumDistinctInvoiceNumbers
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT RegionNumber, InvoiceNumber FROM QueryMatch
    ) qm
GROUP BY qm.RegionNumber
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

...which returns...

```
RegionNumber    NumDistinctInvoiceNumbers
789             1
678             3
```

...lets us know that we need to process RegionNumber 789 first, then assign one of the "leftovers" to RegionNumber 678.

Now, to find the lowest *unused* InvoiceNumber for a given RegionNumber we need to exclude any ones that we have already written to [Table 2]. So, assuming that we have already "given" InvoiceNumber 123 to RegionNumber 789, one way to find a suitable candidate for RegionNumber 678 would be...

```
DMin("InvoiceNumber", "QueryMatch", "RegionNumber=678 AND InvoiceNumber NOT IN (Select InvoiceNumber FROM [Table 2])")
```

...which will return the smallest unused InvoiceNumber, or `Null` if not match is found.

Wrap that up in some VBA code and we get

```
Public Sub AssignInvoicesToRegions()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rstRegion As DAO.Recordset, rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim vInvNo As Variant

Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst2 = cdb.OpenRecordset("Table 2", dbOpenDynaset)

Set rstRegion = cdb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT qm.RegionNumber, Count(qm.InvoiceNumber) AS NumDistinctInvoiceNumbers " & _
            "FROM " & _
                "( " & _
                    "SELECT DISTINCT RegionNumber, InvoiceNumber FROM QueryMatch " & _
                ") qm " & _
            "GROUP BY qm.RegionNumber " & _
            "ORDER BY 2 ASC", _
            dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rstRegion.EOF
    Debug.Print rstRegion!RegionNumber
    vInvNo = DMin("InvoiceNumber", "QueryMatch", "RegionNumber=" & rstRegion!RegionNumber & " " & _
                "AND InvoiceNumber NOT IN (Select Nz(InvoiceNumber, 0) AS InvNo FROM [Table 2])")
    If IsNull(vInvNo) Then
        MsgBox "No available InvoiceNumber for RegionNumber=" & rstRegion!RegionNumber, _
                vbCritical, "Lookup Failed"
    Else
        rst2.FindFirst "RegionNumber=" & rstRegion!RegionNumber
        rst2.Edit
        rst2!InvoiceNumber = vInvNo
        rst2.Update
    End If

    rstRegion.MoveNext
Loop
Debug.Print "Done."
rstRegion.Close
Set rstRegion = Nothing
rst2.Close
Set rst2 = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that in its current form this algorithm is not *guaranteed* to find a match for every RegionNumber. Depending on the order in which the RegionNumber values are processed some regions may find that all of their candidates have been taken (hence the `IsNull()` check in the code). In that case you may have to tweak the algorithm to give those regions "first shot" at an InvoiceNumber, possibly by manually assigning a higher priority to those "difficult" regions.

Comment: thanks, am trying it out now. But one thing can you modify - Table2 is an existing Table with other data. We will be updating Table2 - Setting the InvoiceNumber based on the RegionNumber.

Comment: another quick question @gord , 
What would be the quickest way to round an exact .5  upwards.
Using , Round() in Access queries takes 12.5 to 12 , 12.51 to 13 and 12.49 to 12.
How do we make 12.5 to 13. Possibly a SQL query to do the regular rounding and also take care of these cases.

Update [table] set RoundTotal = round(total)

Comment: @arcotenterprises re: code - updated; re: rounding - Try `Int([fieldname] + 0.5)` (assumes positive numbers).

Comment: Thanks Gord. 
int(5.3 + .5) = Int(5.8) = 6. That is not correct.
What access does - 
12.49 becomes 12 (OK) , 12.5 becomes 12 (Not OK) , 12.51 becomes 13 (OK.) We need to fix that exact .5 case.

Comment: @arcotenterprises No, `Int()` truncates, so `Int(5.8)=5`. Check your work.

Comment: The code

 DMin("InvoiceNumber", "QueryMatch", "RegionNumber=" & rstRegion!RegionNumber & " " & _
                "AND InvoiceNumber NOT IN (Select Nz(InvoiceNumber, 0) AS InvNo FROM [Table 2])"

. There may be a bit of tweaking required. Only One part is updated.
For eg in one set . A - 1 , B - 1 , A - 2 , B  - 2.  Should finally give A - 1 and B - 2. But we get only A - 1. B - 2. is not updated. I feel the DMin code is getting the minimum first and then checking is present in existing list , instead it should be trying to satisfy both.

Comment: @arcotenterprises `DMin()` did work for me (tested with sample data in answer). However, if you think it is failing to find valid results you could always try replacing the `DMin()` call with a block of code that creates and opens a DAO.Recordset using the corresponding SQL statement, and then save the result it returns into `vInvNo`.